# Which voice command has priority?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

How does Glass determine which voice command will have priority?

For example, there are 2 apps with its feature activated by voice command "Jump". Which one will be launched when I give order "Jump"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple apps registered to the same voice command, you will have the option to pick which app to use after you issue the command.

Comment: Cool. Did not have such case before. Did you? Does it prompt you like on Android phones when multiple apps can do some action?

Comment: An easy way to see this is to install the Google Glass Mini-Games: https://developers.google.com/glass/samples/mini-games After you do if you say Play a game, you see a list of items you can say next, this is just like when you say OK Glass and see a list of commands.